# PHP form submit values don't stay put. What do?

Tags: php, forms, post

I've been wanting to create a dynamic editing page for my website. I've been using PHP to do so, and I want to know if I'll have to integrate my MySQL DB so that the changes stay put.

This is what I've done:

first, the items I want changed:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <div class="color">
        <li><a href="?p=home"><?php echo $_POST['homepage'] ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=apendix"><?php echo $_POST['apendix'] ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=about"><?php echo $_POST['about'] ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=contato"><?php echo $_POST['contato'] ?></a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

As it can be seen, I have put the $_POST where I want the menu item names to stay.

Next is the form I have used to do so:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['Carregar'])): 
    $hometitle = $_POST['homepage'];
    $apendix = $_POST['apendix'];
    $aboutMe = $_POST['about'];
    $contact = $_POST['contato'];
endif; 
?>
<div class="section1">
    <h3 style="padding-top:10px;">menu items</h3>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label for=""><?php echo $_POST['homepage'] ?>:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text"  id="home" name="homepage">
        <br>
        <label for="apendice"><?php echo $_POST['apendix'] ?>:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="apendix">
        <br>
        <label for=""><?php echo $_POST['about'] ?>:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="about">
        <br>
        <label for=""><?php echo $_POST['contato'] ?>:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="contato">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Carregar" name="carregar">
    </form>
</div>
```

What happens is that the change is done, but as soon as I go to another page the change is lost, and all the said zones go blank. Can I solve this with PHP only, or will I need to involve MySQL in the deal? If so, how?

Much thanks in advance

Comment: uh, please ignore the lack of </div> closure at the end. It is not so in the original code.

Comment: A database would be a very standard way to do this, but there are other ways to persist data like with a `$_SESSION` or writing to a file on disk.

Comment: Why don't you just edit the question instead of making a silly comment?

Comment: `Carregar` is the value, not the name. `name="carregar"`.

Comment: do you mean that when you click one of the link above, the form will show the value?

Comment: @chris85 thanks. Fixed it,  but the problem is still up.

Comment: @david too. I want both the <li><a>content</a></li> and the <label> to have the $_POST value. It becomes the submitted value after the Carregar button is pressed, but if I go to another page (like homepage, for instance), the values go back to blank.

Comment: of course it will return blank. When you go to another page, there is no $_POST value to be display. $_POST value can only work if you click the submit button in the form that have post method.

Comment: @david so only a database query will do, right?

Comment: it doesn't have to be database query. Just having some input value in the post method form and click the submit button, you will have the $_POST value. Database query is another matter

Comment: Using $_SESSION will solve your problem as comment by @JeffPuckettII

Comment: @david I'm not sure I understood what you mean, but I have put a value ="<?php echo $_POST['desired-item-name'] ?>", and it's not quite what I want. The values already show up, they just don't stay. What I want is that the set value I give to $_POST in my post-method form be kept even after the page is return from, say, ?p=config to ?p=home.

Comment: @SanjivDhakal thanks. I've been thinking now, I think even if it stays put for now, It will return to blank by the time I close the page and return, yes? If so, I think I'll have to recur to a database query

Comment: Why not static instances to persist data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, you will have to persist your data somewhere.

Judging by the behaviour you want it doesn't look like a `$_SESSION` var or even a `$_COOKIE` var will work. The `$_SESSION` is destroyed when your browser is closed. Even if you used a `cookie`, it is local to your browser. Other users will not have access to the data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I imagine a database query is the way to go, then?

Comment: Why not static instances?

Comment: @Waleed I'm practicing on the creation of dynamic objects.

Comment: Yes, if it needs to be dynamic. You would also need to consider the implication of the data not being returned i.e: DB failure - how will your app handle it? can you fallback to sane defaults? etc.

Comment: @kaizenCoder Will do. I'll study some more and have it go. Thank you for the help!